# If having an initial value, How can I create a function so this initial value is multiplied recursively with a list?

Tags: list

So I have an array with some daily price variations (VarP), and a initial price value (p_0 = 500), and I want to get a new array with prices according to these variations.
For example:

```
p_0 = 500
p_1 = p_0*VarP[0]
p_2 = p_1*VarP[1]
.
.
.
p_n = p_(n-1)*VarP[n-1]
```

How can I do this with a function in Python?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
newArr = [None] * len(VarP);
newArr[0] = 500;
for i in range(1, len(VarP)):    
    newArr[i] = VarP[i-1] * newArr[i-1]
```